# Rails cancan can :manage all Offers as moderator which belong to the same Department

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :department
  has_many :offers
end

class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

The user class has an attribute of role. I want the :moderator role to be able to manage all Offers of all Users which have the same department.id as the :moderator. Thus far I've come up with the following:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.is? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    elsif user.is? :moderator
      # Moderators can manage Users which belong to the same Department
      can :manage, User, :department_id => user.department_id
      # Moderators can manage all Offers which share the same department.id as the manager
      can :manage, Offer, :department => { :id => user.department_id}
    elsif user.is? :registered
      # User can manage their own Offers
      can :manage, Offer, :user_id => user.id
    else
      can :read, Offer
    end
  end
end
```

But the line

```
can :manage, Offer, :department => { :id => user.department_id}
```

shows all Offers, not only the one I need. Any idea how to change the line? Maybe a scope in the Offer model?

Comment: How are offers and departments linked?

Comment: not directly but through the user model: a = Offer.first; a.user.department_id delivers me the department.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
can :manage, Offer do |offer|
  offer.user.department == user.department
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Ju Liu's answer worked, also adding

```
has_one :department, :through => :user
```

to the Offer model and using my original definition of

```
can :manage, Offer, :department => { :id => user.department_id}
```

seems to do the trick.